# how to modify _xspAppSearchSubmit on Application Layout Xpages

Tags: xpages

Im trying to modify search parameter in Application Layout Search, to accept dot(.) as literal part of search item for filtering a view..

> for example...
>   "Mr. Smith" will not show up in the view, but
>   "Mr.Smith" will..

digging deeper with google debugger, I found the function `_xspAppSearchSubmit` where I can simply change the code `encodeURIComponent(val)` into `encodeURIComponent(val.replace(/s+\.s+/g,'')`
which worked when i tested on console. The `s+` to remove spaces, `\.` to keep the dot as literal.

BUT somehow, I cannot find this function in the `ApplicationLayout1` custom control, and listed only one event - `onItemClick`. 
Is it possible to add an "onChange" event?

There's an option and optionParam property there but not sure how to apply this.

Im a newbie with xpage and this control, can someone help me work around this, I've checked other sites about this but doesn't explain this kind of issue. I've also checked `encodeURIComponent` functionality, but it still interprets dot as command. I also learned this dot works like `*` wildcard.

the Application Layout is `ccBaseUI` from "One UI", and setup Basic Application Configuration.

[code snippet capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU5Kb.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your comments

Comment: thanks Per Henrik, updated my post

Comment: hi again, recently I found a possible command from jquery.proxy() which is the closest way i can modify a generated function.. next issue is where exactly will i place this, before Application Layout, or inside Application Layout - before the query.. but im doing trial and error, anyway..